# Making interactive menu with table method

Tags: html, css

I have written some codes of html & have given style to it. it's same page of bootstrap home page. But just for my practice. Everything is fine but I cannot make top menu navigation same as bootstrap. I mean when I hover over the menu a background should appear behind that menu. it should be of different size for each menu. So, I think I have to define blocks for each li, so how can I do that. Please refer to bootrap home page to know about top menu. Thank you.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    body{
        background-color: #5C4283;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #topBar{
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
    }

    #bootstrap{
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #5C4283;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 12px;
        margin-left: 100px;     
    }

    #topMenu{
        margin-top: 0;
        float: left;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #5C4283;         
        height: 35px;   
        padding-top: 15px;          
    }

    #topMenu li{
        list-style-type: none;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;                             
    }   

    #topMenu ul{
        margin: 0;      
    }

    #topMenu a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #topSideMenu{
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-left: 430px;
        float: left;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #5C4283;
    }
    #topSideMenu li{        
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    #topSideMenu ul{
        margin: 0;
    }

    #logoLink{
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
        width : 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #wrapper{
        margin-top: 100px;
        width: 100%;    
    }

    #container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:150px;
    }
    #bootText{
        font-size: 110px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    #logoText{
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: Arial;
        text-align: center;
        word-spacing: 5px;
        line-height: 130%;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    #downloadBoot{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 250px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    #dwnBootstrap{
        display: block;
        width: 250px;
        height: 60px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #dwnBootstrap:hover{
        background-color: white;
        color: #5C4283;
    }

    #dwnText{
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 17px;
    }

    #versionTxt{
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    #adBlock{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 330px;
        height: 130px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #adpic{
        margin-top: 16px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 130px;
        height: 100px;  
        position: absolute;     
    }

    #adtext{
        width: 150px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: 16px; 
        margin-left: 160px;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 13px;
        word-spacing: 1px;
    }

    #adlink{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    #adsvia{
        opacity: 0.4;
    }

    #restbody{
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1900px;
        margin-top: 80px;
    }

    #upperPart{
        margin-top: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #uppertext{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 665px;
    }

    #everyone{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 45px;
        color: #3F3333;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #bottomtext{
        width: 920px;
        margin: 0 auto;     
    }

    #front-end{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 23px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #555555;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #firstimage{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        width: 380px;
        height: 300px;      
        text-align: center; 
        float: left;    
    }

    #img01headingtxt{
        margin-top: 15px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #img01text{
        margin-top: 5px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    #secondimage{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 30px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;      
        text-align: center; 
        float: left;    
    }

    #img02headingtxt{
        margin-top: 15px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #img02text{
        margin-top: 5px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    #thirdimage{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-right: 40px;     
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;      
        text-align: center; 
        float: right;   
    }

    #img03headingtxt{
        margin-top: 15px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #img03text{
        margin-top: 5px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    #images{
        width: 100%;
        height: 330px;      
    }

    #firstline{
        margin-top: 40px;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        opacity: 0.2;
        width: 120px;
    }

    #singleline{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #55555B;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    #gifthubbtn{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 250px;       
    }

    #gifthub{
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #563D7C;
        border-radius: 7px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 45px;
        text-decoration: none;      
        text-align: center;
        color: #551A8B;
    }

    #gifthub:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: #563D7C;
    }

    #gifthubtxt{
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        font-family: Calibri;
    }

    #secondline{
        margin-top: 100px;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        opacity: 0.3;       
    }

    #builtWith{
        margin-top: 110px;
    }

    #builtwithtxt{
        font-size: 45px;
        font-family: Calibri;
        text-align: center;
        color: #333333;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #builtwithbtm{
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #builtwithbtmtxt{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 24px;        
        color: #555555;
        text-align: center; 
        margin-top: 5px;    
    }

    #collection{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #428BCA;
    }

    #collection:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #2a6496;
    }

    #btmimagecontainer{
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    #btmimages{
        width: 1141px;
        height: 229px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #btmimagetxt{
        margin-top: 70px;
    }

    #explorebtn{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 250px;
    }

    #explore{
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #563D7C;
        border-radius: 7px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 45px;
        text-decoration: none;      
        text-align: center;
        color: #551A8B;
    }

    #exploretxt{
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        font-family: Calibri;
    }

    #explore:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: #563D7C;
    }

    #links{
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #sociallinks{
        width: 614px;
        margin: 0 auto;     
    }

    #firstlink{
        float: left;
        width: 105px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    #secondlink{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 110px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    #thirdlink{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 235px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    #fourthlink{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 104px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    #footer{
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #footertxtarea{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 510px;           
    }

    #footertxt{     
        color: #7777A4;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;                 
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="topBar">
        <div id="bootstrap">Bootstrap</div>     
        <div id="topMenu">
            <ul>
                <li id="firstli"><a href="">Getting Started</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="secondli">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Javascript</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Customize</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
        <div id="topSideMenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Expo</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
    </div>  
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">            
            <a id="logoLink"><p id="bootText">B</p></a>     
        </div>
        <div  id="logoText">
            Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for <br>developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
        </div>
        <div id="downloadBoot">
            <a href="" id="dwnBootstrap"><p id="dwnText">Download Bootstrap</p></a><p id="versionTxt">Currently v3.3.0</p>
        </div>
        <div id="adBlock">
            <div id="adpic">
                <a href=""><img src="ad pic.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="adtext">
                <p>We connect highly qualified audiences with highly relevant services, products, and brands.</p>
                <p><a href="" id="adlink"><span id="adsvia">ads via </span>Carbon</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="restbody">
            <div id="upperPart">
                <div id="uppertext">
                    <p id="everyone">Designed for everyone, everywhere.</p>
                </div>

                <div id="bottomtext">
                    <p id="front-end">Bootstrap makes front-end web development faster and easier. It's made for folks of all skill levels, devices of all shapes, and projects of all sizes.</p>
                </div><hr id="firstline">
                <div id="images">
                <div id="firstimage">               
                    <img src="img01.jpg" />
                    <p id="img01headingtxt">Preprocessors</p>
                    <p id="img01text">Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code utilizes the two most popular CSS preprocessors, Less and Sass. Quickly get started with precompiled CSS or build on the source.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="secondimage">              
                    <img src="img02.jpg" />
                    <p id="img02headingtxt">One framework, every device.</p>
                    <p id="img02text">Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.</p>
                </div>      
                <div id="thirdimage">               
                    <img src="img03.jpg" />
                    <p id="img03headingtxt">Full of features</p>
                    <p id="img03text">With Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome jQuery plugins.</p>
                </div>
                </div>      
                <hr id="firstline">
                <div>
                    <p id="singleline">Bootstrap is open source. It's hosted, developed, and maintained on GitHub.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="gifthubbtn">
                    <a href="" id="gifthub"><p id="gifthubtxt">View the GiftHub Project</p></a>
                </div>
                <hr id="secondline">
                <div id="builtWith">
                    <p id="builtwithtxt">Built with Bootstrap.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="builtwithbtm">
                    <p id="builtwithbtmtxt">Millions of amazing sites across the web are being built with Bootstrap. Get started on your own with our growing <a href="" id="collection">collection of examples</a> or by exploring some of our favorites.</p>
                </div>
                <hr id="firstline">
                <div id="btmimagecontainer">
                    <div id="btmimages">
                        <a href=""><img src="btmimage.jpg"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="btmimagetxt">
                    <p id="builtwithbtmtxt">We showcase dozens of inspiring projects built with Bootstrap on the Bootstrap Expo.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="explorebtn">
                    <a href="" id="explore"><p id="exploretxt">Explore the Expo</p></a>
                </div>
                <hr id="secondline" />
                <div id="links">
                    <div id="sociallinks">
                        <div id="firstlink">
                            <a href=""><img src="link01.jpg" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="secondlink">
                            <a href=""><img src="link02.jpg" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="thirdlink">
                            <a href=""><img src="link03.jpg" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="fourthlink">
                            <a href=""><img src="link04.jpg" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <div id="footertxtarea">
                        <p id="footertxt">Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat. <br> Maintained by the core team with the help of our contributors. <br> Code licensed under MIT, documentation under CC BY 3.0.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the css change, that will make your top menu look like bootstrap page (fiddle : [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vgtvhbkz/))

--Remove the 'margin-right' from '#topMenu li' 
 --Added Padding to '#topMenu ul li a' 
 --Added background and hover styles to '#topMenu ul li a'

```
    body{
        background-color: #5C4283;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #topBar{
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
    }

    #bootstrap{
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #5C4283;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 12px;
        margin-left: 100px;     
    }

    #topMenu{
        margin-top: 0;
        float: left;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #5C4283;         
        height: 35px;   
        padding-top: 15px;          
    }

    #topMenu li{
        list-style-type: none;
        float: left;

    }   

    #topMenu ul{
        margin: 0;      
    }

    #topMenu a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #topSideMenu{
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-left: 430px;
        float: left;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #5C4283;
    }
    #topSideMenu li{        
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    #topSideMenu ul{
        margin: 0;
    }

    #logoLink{
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
        width : 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #wrapper{
        margin-top: 100px;
        width: 100%;    
    }

    #container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:150px;
    }
    #bootText{
        font-size: 110px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    #logoText{
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: Arial;
        text-align: center;
        word-spacing: 5px;
        line-height: 130%;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    #downloadBoot{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 250px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    #dwnBootstrap{
        display: block;
        width: 250px;
        height: 60px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #dwnBootstrap:hover{
        background-color: white;
        color: #5C4283;
    }

    #dwnText{
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 17px;
    }

    #versionTxt{
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    #adBlock{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 330px;
        height: 130px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #adpic{
        margin-top: 16px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 130px;
        height: 100px;  
        position: absolute;     
    }

    #adtext{
        width: 150px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: 16px; 
        margin-left: 160px;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 13px;
        word-spacing: 1px;
    }

    #adlink{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    #adsvia{
        opacity: 0.4;
    }

    #restbody{
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1900px;
        margin-top: 80px;
    }

    #upperPart{
        margin-top: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #uppertext{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 665px;
    }

    #everyone{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 45px;
        color: #3F3333;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #bottomtext{
        width: 920px;
        margin: 0 auto;     
    }

    #front-end{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 23px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #555555;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #firstimage{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        width: 380px;
        height: 300px;      
        text-align: center; 
        float: left;    
    }

    #img01headingtxt{
        margin-top: 15px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #img01text{
        margin-top: 5px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    #secondimage{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 30px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;      
        text-align: center; 
        float: left;    
    }

    #img02headingtxt{
        margin-top: 15px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #img02text{
        margin-top: 5px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    #thirdimage{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-right: 40px;     
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;      
        text-align: center; 
        float: right;   
    }

    #img03headingtxt{
        margin-top: 15px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #img03text{
        margin-top: 5px;
        color: #3E3733;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    #images{
        width: 100%;
        height: 330px;      
    }

    #firstline{
        margin-top: 40px;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        opacity: 0.2;
        width: 120px;
    }

    #singleline{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #55555B;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    #gifthubbtn{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 250px;       
    }

    #gifthub{
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #563D7C;
        border-radius: 7px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 45px;
        text-decoration: none;      
        text-align: center;
        color: #551A8B;
    }

    #gifthub:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: #563D7C;
    }

    #gifthubtxt{
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        font-family: Calibri;
    }

    #secondline{
        margin-top: 100px;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        opacity: 0.3;       
    }

    #builtWith{
        margin-top: 110px;
    }

    #builtwithtxt{
        font-size: 45px;
        font-family: Calibri;
        text-align: center;
        color: #333333;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #builtwithbtm{
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #builtwithbtmtxt{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 24px;        
        color: #555555;
        text-align: center; 
        margin-top: 5px;    
    }

    #collection{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #428BCA;
    }

    #collection:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #2a6496;
    }

    #btmimagecontainer{
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    #btmimages{
        width: 1141px;
        height: 229px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #btmimagetxt{
        margin-top: 70px;
    }

    #explorebtn{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 250px;
    }

    #explore{
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #563D7C;
        border-radius: 7px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 45px;
        text-decoration: none;      
        text-align: center;
        color: #551A8B;
    }

    #exploretxt{
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        font-family: Calibri;
    }

    #explore:hover{
        color: white;
        background-color: #563D7C;
    }

    #links{
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #sociallinks{
        width: 614px;
        margin: 0 auto;     
    }

    #firstlink{
        float: left;
        width: 105px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    #secondlink{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 110px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    #thirdlink{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 235px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    #fourthlink{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 104px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    #footer{
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #footertxtarea{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 510px;           
    }

    #footertxt{     
        color: #7777A4;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;                 
    }
#topMenu ul li a:hover{
    background-color:red;
    display:block;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#topMenu ul li a{
    background-color:white;
    display:block;
    padding:15px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menu item appearance to change, for example:

a white background menu item with black text.

```
#menuitem {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
}
```

but once the user hovers over it to change inverse in color, you use a pseudo-class:

```
#menuitem:hover {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
```

This would make the appearance change when the mouse is over it.

Is that what you wanted to achieve?